# `short int` vs `int`

Tags: c++, integer, short

Should I bother using `short int` instead of `int`? Is there any useful difference? Any pitfalls?

Comment: I added a question to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What Ben said. You will actually create less efficient code since all the registers need to strip out the upper bits whenever any comparisons are done. Unless you need to save memory because you have tons of them, use the native integer size. That's what `int` is for.

EDIT: Didn't even see your sub-question about const. Using const on intrinsic types (int, float) is useless, but any pointers/references should absolutely be const whenever applicable. Same for class methods as well.

Comment: For "intrinsic" types, `const` can make a difference depending on the context: a static member constant or a free constant of integral type will be *compile time constants* and as such can be used in places where variables cannot, as for example as the number of elements in an array. Note, nevertheless that not all constants can be regarded as *compile time constants*, but that at any rate the compiler might be able to use the extra information while optimizing.

Comment: Most compilers will not consider a `const int` a compile-time constant - after all, unless the function is inlined (or the function call happens in the same .cpp file), the compiler can't even know the value is. But even if it IS inlined, compilers will typically still not recognize a `const int` argument as a constant expression and throw a compile error.

Comment: **–1**  “Using const on intrinsic types (int, float) is useless“” is incorrect and very misleading as purported fact, and absurdly wrongheaded as advice.

Comment: I agree, with Cheers. Since const is meant to give compiler support to the semantic meaning of a variable that shouldn't change, const should be used on a primitive/intrinsic type in every instance that it would be used elsewhere. To do otherwise would be like choosing whether to use a bowl or plate depending on if it was ordered or home-cooked (an implementation fact, similar to pointer vs copy) instead of what food it is; good luck eating your soup!

Comment: I think if you're going to be promoting to the native register size, you might as well go all the way and use long these days. The assembly is likely going to be the same, and long has a chance of being able to encode pointers on 64 bit architectures, unlike int. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think long is the new int (at least as far as function return types and parameters are concerned).

Answer (score 16):

#### short vs int

Don't bother with `short` unless there is a really good reason such as saving memory on a gazillion values, or conforming to a particular memory layout required by other code.

Using lots of different integer types just introduces complexity and possible wrap-around bugs.

On modern computers it might also introduce needless inefficiency.

#### const

Sprinkle `const` liberally wherever you can.

`const` constrains what might change, making it easier to understand the code: you know that this beastie is not gonna move, so, can be ignored, and thinking directed at more useful/relevant things.

Top-level `const` for formal arguments is however by convention omitted, possibly because the gain is not enough to outweight the added verbosity.

Also, in a pure declaration of a function top-level `const` for an argument is simply ignored by the compiler. But on the other hand, some other tools may not be smart enough to ignore them, when comparing pure declarations to definitions, and one person cited that in an earlier debate on the issue in the comp.lang.c++ Usenet group. So it depends to some extent on the toolchain, but happily I've never used tools that place any significance on those `const`s.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: By "top-level const" you mean this, right? function( const int topLevelArgument );

Comment: Top-level const is only disregarded by the compiler in the declaration, but not in the definition: `void foo(int);` and `void foo( const int );` are equivalent forward declarations. But in the actual function definition, the added const will have the compiler complain if you try to change the value: `void foo( const int x ) { ++x; }` is a compiler error, while `void foo( int x ) { ++x; }` is fine. Note that `void foo(int);` is a forward declaration for either of them (as `void foo( const int );`

Comment: @David: interesting comment. what did i write that you felt was unclear?

Comment: @Alf: I did not feel that it was clear enough that the `const` will not be ignored in the function definition --it is clear that in the declaration it is ignored.

Comment: What happens on 64-bit CPUs when compilers still use `int` as a 32-bit number? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use the CPU's native size instead? It's common nowadays that this expression is true: `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int*)`

Comment: @GetFree: The 64-bit model with 32-bit int is the one used in Windows. I'm not aware of any problems with it (as a former Windows programmer still doing some hobby stuff). It can have some advantages in that e.g. an array of 32-bit `int` might fit in a cache, while a corresponding array of 64-bit `int` wouldn't.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I'm not sure about the first part. I just tested that `sizeof` expression in gcc 6.3 and I got `4 != 8`

Comment: @GetFree: Assuming that `4 != 8` means that `int` is size 4 and `void*` is size 8, that's what you get with 32-bit `int` in 64-bit programming. The `int` is 32 bits. The pointer, `void*`, is 64 bits.

So, I don't understand what you mean by “I'm not sure about the first part”. What do you mean?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, you said that's the model used in Windows. So I went to check what happens in Linux, I and got the same result. It seems that `int` is still 4 bytes everywhere.

Comment: @GetFree: OK, now it's more clear what you're asking: which systems use 64-bit `int`? [Wikipedia's article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) has some examples. I do not know of any reasonably exhaustive list of such systems, sorry.

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely not in function arguments.  Few calling conventions are going to make any distinction between short and int.  If you're making giant arrays you could use `short` if your data fits in `short` to save memory and increase cache effectiveness.

Answer (score 1):

The question is technically malformed "Should I use `short int`?". The only good answer will be "I don't know, what are you trying to accomplish?".

But let's consider some scenarios:

1. You **know** the definite range of values that your variable can take.

The ranges for signed integers are:

- `signed char` — -2⁷ – 2⁷-1
- `short` — -2¹⁵ – 2¹⁵-1
- `int` — -2¹⁵ – 2¹⁵-1
- `long` — -2³¹ – 2³¹-1
- `long long` — -2⁶³ – 2⁶³-1

We should note here that these are guaranteed ranges, they can be larger in your particular implementation, and often are. You are also guaranteed that the previous range cannot be larger than the next, but they can be equal.

You will quickly note that `short` and `int` actually have the same guaranteed range. This gives you very little incentive to use it. The only reason to use `short` given this situation becomes giving other coders a hint that the values will be not too large, but this can be done via a comment.

It does, however, make sense to use `signed char`, if you know that you can fit **every potential value** in the range -128 — 127.

2. You don't know the exact range of potential values.

In this case you are in a rather bad position to attempt to minimise memory useage, and should probably use at least `int`. Although it has the same minimum range as `short`, on many platforms it may be larger, and this will help you out.

But the bigger problem is that you are trying to write a piece of software that operates on values, the range of which you do not know. Perhaps something wrong has happened before you have started coding (when requirements were being written up).

3. You have an idea about the range, but realise that it can change in the future.

Ask yourself how close to the boundary are you. If we are talking about something that goes from -1000 to +1000 and can potentially change to -1500 – 1500, then by all means use `short`. The specific architecture may pad your value, which will mean you won't save any space, but you won't lose anything. However, if we are dealing with some quantity that is currently -14000 – 14000, and can grow unpredictably (perhaps it's some financial value), then don't just switch to `int`, go to `long` right away. You will lose some memory, but will save yourself a lot of headache catching these roll-over bugs.

Comment: Look at the revision history of the question, there was a question about `const` that has been removed

Answer (score -1):

**short vs int** - If your data will fit in a short, use a short. Save memory. Make it easier for the reader to know how much data your variable may fit.

**use of const** - Great programming practice. If your data should be a const then make it const. It is very helpful when someone reads your code.

Comment: "Save memory" - not really. What you save in memory you'll end up paying in extra code, and then some! Unless it's an array, don't do it. Besides, if your short is embedded in ints, the structure padding will reduce your memory savings to zero.