# When to use short instead of int?

Tags: c

Two use cases for which I would consider `short` come to mind:

1. I want an integer type that's at least 16 bits in size
2. I want an integer type that's exactly 16 bits in size

In the first case, since `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits and is the most efficient integral data type, I would use `int`. In the second case, since the standard doesn't guarantee that `short`'s size is exactly 16 bit, I would use `int16_t` instead. So what use is short?

Comment: possible duplicate of [`short int` vs `int`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445303/short-int-vs-int)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is never a reason to use `short` in a C99 environment that has 16-bit integers; you can use `int16_t`, `int_fast16_t` or `int_least16_t` instead.

The main reasons for using `short` is backward compatibility with C89 or older environments, which do not offer these types, or with libraries using `short` as part of their public API, for implementing `<stdint.h>` itself, or for compatibility with platforms that do not have 16-bit integers so their C compilers do not provide `int16_t`.

Comment: Also for APIs that use `short` as part of a structure or function interface (e.g. a function that takes `short *` as an argument). That's really the **only** reason I would ever use `short` in modern code.

Comment: If you use EntityFramework with code first, `int16` will also be used for the database fields which reduces the reqired amount of space for each row.

Answer (score 3):

ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99) adds headers [`<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html#tag_13_48) and [`<inttypes.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html#tag_13_20) that provide what you need:

- `int16_t` might not be defined, but if there is a 16-bit (exactly) integer type in the implementation, `int16_t` will be an alias for it.
- `int_least16_t` is a type that is the smallest type that holds at least 16 bits.  It is always available.
- `int_fast16_t` is the fastest type that holds at least 16 bits.  It is always available.

Similarly for other sizes: 8, 16, 32, 64.

There's also `intmax_t` for the maximum precision integer type.  Of course, there's also an unsigned type for each of these: `uint16_t` etc.

These types are also present in C2011.  They were not present in C89 or C90.  However, I believe that the headers are available in some shape or form for most compilers, even those like MS Visual C, that do not claim to provide support for C99.

Note that I've given links to the POSIX 2008 versions of the `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` headers.  POSIX imposes rules on the implementation that the C standard does not:

> #### §7.18.1.1 Exact-width integer types
>
> ¶1 The typedef name `int`*N*`_t` designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding
>   bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, `int8_t` denotes a signed integer
>   type with a width of exactly 8 bits.
>
> ¶2 The typedef name `uint`*N*`_t` designates an unsigned integer type with width N. Thus,
>   `uint24_t` denotes an unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.
>
> ¶3 These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with
>   widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you really want a particular data size you use int16_t, int32_t, etc.

int16_t is usually a platform-specific typedef from short (or whatever maps to 16 bits).  On a 32-bit machine, int16_t may be typedef'd as short, on a 16-bit machine int16_t may be typedef as int.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI C specifies minimum value ranges for types.  You can only be sure of the first case; not the second.

Comment: You can be sure of `int16_t` having 16 bits width in C99.

Comment: @larsmans: yes, you can be sure that _if it is defined_ then `int16_t` will have exactly 16 bits.  You can't be sure it will be defined (in theory; this is one of those places where practice is simpler than the theory, in general, unless perhaps you're working on a Cray).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very large array you might want to use shorts.

You might find them useful for picking out pieces of some other data as part of a union.

Comment: If you have a very large array of 16-bit values, you can also use an `int16_t[]`.